# Check if the current date is between two dates + mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have the following table :

```
id     dateStart     dateEnd      active
1      2012-11-12    2012-12-31   0
2      2012-11-12    2012-12-31   0
```

I want to check if today's date is in between `dateStart` and `dateEnd`.

The following is my query for this :

```
$todaysDate="2012-26-11";
$db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
$result = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=0 AND {$todaysDate} between dateStart and dateEnd");
return $result;
```

But so far it's not working as it returns zero rows.

Comment: "But its not working." Can you be more specific? What is the error?

Comment: @Mark Byres : It returning 0 rows. Blank.

Comment: what is the dateformat of $todaysDate?

Comment: date format is same : 2012-26-11

Comment: as pritaeas has pointed out the format is different in month and days

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this :: This will solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=0 AND CURDATE() between dateStart and dateEnd
```

Comment: is it CURRDATE() or CURDATE() ?

Comment: can anybody tell me how this can be done in laravel?

Comment: @Sashi Kant you are SQL ninja

Answer (score 4):

MySQL uses YYYY-MM-DD by default:

```
$todaysDate="2012-26-11";
```

should be:

```
$todaysDate="2012-11-26";
```

And you need single quotes around it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE CURDATE() between reg_start_date and reg_end_date") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to put single quotes around the changed date:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=0 AND '{$todaysDate}' between dateStart and dateEnd"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $date=date("m/d/Y");
   $data=$this->Comman_model->select_manuvl('select * from company_news_details where userid='.$_SESSION['user_key'].' 
     AND "'.$date.'" between `rdate` 
     AND `edate`');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this use ""

```
$todaysDate="2012-26-11";
$db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
$result = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=0 AND "{$todaysDate}" between dateStart and dateEnd");
return $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$todaysDate="2012-11-26";//changed date
$db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
$select=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE active=0 AND {$todaysDate} between dateStart and dateEnd");
$result = $select->fetchAll();
return $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the {} as described below.

```
$todaysDate="2012-11-26";//changed date
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE '$todaysDate' between reg_start_date and reg_end_date") or die(mysql_error());
```