# SQL compare dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate if a date is between a few dates that are in my database.1

For example:
I have the date: `29-02-2016`

I have some entries in my database that have 2 columns, a `start date` and a `end date`.

Now I want to select rows of my database that collide with the example date.
All the dates are in timestamps.

So for example I have in my database the next rows:

```
start date: 11-2-2016 => end date: 12-2-2016  //does not match
start date: 28-2-2016 => end date: 30-2-2016  //does match
```

Does anyone know how to select them from my database?

Comment: use `between` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the current date is between two dates + mysql select query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563423/check-if-the-current-date-is-between-two-dates-mysql-select-query)

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to select the rows where your_date is in between `start_date` and `end_date` ? A simple `between` clause would do that.

```
select * from your_table
where your_date between start_date and end_date
```

Comment: @Utsav This should be marked as duplicate instead of giving another answer

Comment: @haytem - Marked it too. Thanks.