# How to find Current Date is between Fromdate and todate

Tags: mysql

I have Customers Booking Table where multiple customers are there also one customer can have multiple orders so  from that table i have to find which is current or active order of Customer.There are two column From Date and To date.I want to trace order of customer which is active and want answer count of orders of customer is active.

Comment: It's too trivial. You should have searched first.`.....CURDATE() BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate....`

Comment: Was gping to post that as an answer, but maybe not...

Comment: that sounds like a pretty straight-forward job. just add 2 conditions. something like `where currDate > Fromdate and currDate < todate`(you can set <= where you want. i didn't know so..well, hope you got the idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the current date is between two dates + mysql select query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563423/check-if-the-current-date-is-between-two-dates-mysql-select-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CURDATE() between fromdate and todate
```

Answer (score 1):

use Select Case and Between

```
Select
      Order_id,Customer_id,
      Case When CURDATE() BETWEEN FromDate And ToDate Then 'Active' Else 'Inactive' End as [Status] 
From Order_table
```

**UPDATE**

```
Select 
      Count(*) as Total,Customer_id 
From 
     Ordertable 
Where 
      CURDATE() BETWEEN FromDate And ToDate And Customer_id = custid
Group By Customer_id
```

I used Group By to avoid displaying same data repeatedly

Comment: What if I want to find this for particular customer and have to display count of that.

Comment: Check the second part

Comment: Thank You for solving this .

Comment: Glad it helped you